# How to enable iCloud music or link Apple music to my account on macOS Catalina?

Tags: itunes, icloud

[image]

When I try to turn on "Sync Library" in Catalina's new Music App I get this error:

> This account does not have iCloud music enabled.
>
> Apple music has not been linked to this account.

[image]

I do indeed have an iCloud subscription, so storage shouldn't be an issue.

How do I enable iClound music on my account?

Comment: Do you have an Apple music subscription?

Comment: No I do not have one.

Comment: I believe that synching your music library with iCloud is a feature of Apple Music, so you need that too.

Comment: Why do you believe that? Would be very nice to have a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually more a feature of iTunes Match which is included in Apple Music but can also be purchased separately.

> iTunes Match gives you access to all of your music on all of your devices, even songs that you've imported from other sources such as CDs.

([source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146))

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature of Apple Music and you [need a subscription to it to use it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204926).